# Cannot find server when run stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a database backup from a client. This database has a SP that I am trying to execute. I am getting the following message:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure SP_NAME, Line 24
> [Batch Start Line 2]
> Could not find server 'InstanceName' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

I also looked into inside of the SP and see that it references tables that are not in the DB I am running the stored prog from, they are in another DB. Somehow the stored prog runs fine on the client side. The client says they do not use any linked server. Any idea what my error message actual means?

Thanks

Comment: It means, as you discovered, there's a nother database that you don't have.  It works for the client probably because they _do_ have that database on their SQL Server isntance.  Ask the client for a backup of that database as well.

Comment: "`Somehow the stored prog runs fine on the client side.`" Of course it does, because their server has a link setup to the other database, which is naturally not possible to include in a backup. Remember, a single server can host many databases, but that backup only contains one of them.

Comment: I do have another DB. How do I setup a link between two DBs?

Comment: How does the procedure refer to the other db?  If it's a direct db.schema.object reference then restoring the db on your instance _with the same name_ should be sufficient.

Comment: Nope, it's not using db.schema.object format.

Comment: So what's it using then?

Comment: Just a table name. However, I am more confused by the error message. The client is saying they do not use linked servers.

Comment: It can't be just using a table name.  Post the code so we can see what it's doing.

Comment: I understand that it's impossible to reference a table from another DB using just a name. I am trying to take it back to the client pointing out to the error message. Looks like they have some kind of configuration that allows referencing tables just by names.

Comment: Ah, look for a synonym with the name of the "table" that you're looking at.  That is what would look like a table but actually refer to an object external to the database.

Comment: this select * from sys.synonyms shows this: JCCH 1739153241 NULL 1 0 SN SYNONYM 2017-11-24 10:27:25.287 2017-11-24 10:27:25.287 0 0 0 [Instance_name].[Viewpoint].[dbo].[bJCCH]. JCCH is a table name from the SP. Now I understand where the error is coming from. What do I need to ask the client to make it work on my box?

Comment: Or a view `CREATE VIEW dbo.viewname AS SELECT * FROM dbname.dbo.tablename;`

Comment: There you go.  You need to ask the client for a back up of the Viewpoint database the synonym refers to.

Comment: But I have it already. do I need to change Instance name in [Instance_name].[Viewpoint].[dbo].[bJCCH] to my local instance name?

Comment: Ok, then yes.  If you already have that db then you need to update the synonym.  You can either change `Instance_name` to your instance's name, or just remove `Instance_name` altogether since your copy is on the same server instance.  And by "update" I mean drop and recreate the synonym since they can't be altered after creation.

Comment: Or simply fully qualify table name in the stored prog, right?

Comment: @Mark Could, but if the code is going to be shipped back to the client it's better to leave the synonym.

Comment: Note - your client was wrong when they told you they do not use linked servers. Do NOT trust that your client fully understands their system and how it works. Bonus points - point this out (gracefully) and suggest they update (more likely create) an actual disaster recovery plan with complete and accurate details about their own system.